# References on piecewise linear functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I've been looking for references on **piecewise linear functions** in analysis books but I can't find many. Some treat the subject a bit passing and not general. Do you know of any references that might be useful?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Piecewise linear (or affine) **and continuous** ? Being restricted to a certain domain [a,b] and "clamped" at the border (with $f(a)=f(b)=0$) ?  In this case they can be considered as spline curves with degree 1. Otherwise, they have the fundamental property of being sums of (non necessarily symmetric) "tent functions".

Comment: @JeanMarie: I was thinking not continuous and not necessarily over a domain of the form [a,b].

Answer (score 4):

There is a whole tome entitled [Introduction to Piecewise Linear Topology](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540111023) by Rourke and Sanderson. It probably (almost certainly?) has too much information in comparison with what you want to know. But it also contains the basics.